# Why "Nearby Message" does not subscribe to Beacon Message

Tags: android, kotlin, google-play-services, google-nearby

Nearby Message API Does not subscribe to Beacon Message. What am I supposed to do?

I finished testing whether "Nearby Message" works in Android 7.0 and Android 9.0. And I referenced this document(https://developers.google.com/nearby/messages/android/get-beacon-messages) but, it is still not working.

```
listener = object: MessageListener() {
    override fun onFound(msg: Message) {
        Log.i(TAG, "Found: $msg")
    }

    override fun onLost(msg: Message) {
        Log.i(TAG, "Lost: $msg")
    }
}


val options = SubscribeOptions.Builder()
    .setStrategy(Strategy.BLE_ONLY)
    .build()
Nearby.getMessagesClient(this).subscribe(listener, options)
```

Nearby Message is subscribed to, but beacon message is not.

Answer (score 0):

For messages, it needs both to be in *Nearby* with Manifest ...

```
<meta-data
    android:name="com.google.android.nearby.messages.API_KEY"
    android:value="Your-Key-from-Google Developer Console." />
```

Please follow this [NearbyDevices getting-started](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-nearby/tree/master/messages/NearbyDevices#getting-started) .
or another from the same [GitHub repo](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-nearby) 
Here, API Key is the "key"-thing !

[e.g. Your-Key-from-Google Developer Console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CjNVN.png)